# Android SwipeRefreshLayout stops RecycleView from scrolling

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I have a group horizontal `RecycleViews` inside a `SwipeRefreshLayout` and I am having trouble with swiping the `Recycleviews` on the start of the page as it keeps stopping it and detecting a refresh swipe.

How to stop this from happening?

Or is there a way to trigger refresh only if not swiping?

Also, is this the best way to implement my desired layout?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_swipe_refresh_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
                android:isScrollContainer="false"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/block_border"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/trending_episodes_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <!--This is the first affected recycle  -->

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/trendingEpisodesRecycle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />

                </LinearLayout>


                <!--This is the Second affected recycle  -->

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/allNewsRecycle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/title_top"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@drawable/block_border"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/moods_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/title_top"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/moodsRecycle"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:clipToPadding="false"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so I solved this problem by disabling the SwipeRefreshLayout when the RecycleView is being touched, and re-enabling it again once the user let go of the RecycleView.

Bellow are the code for that from my program:

```
        MyRecycleView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(final RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
            {

                super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView,newState);
                if (newState != RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) { // on scroll stop
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setEnabled(true);
                }

            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zaid answer works fine. But in my case I had horizontal recycle views inside adapter, so for me it would be hard to connect adapter with activity recycler.
Easier approach is to create custom VerticalRefreshLayout and use it instead of SwipeRefreshLayout.

Kotlin solution:

```
class VerticalRefreshLayout(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : SwipeRefreshLayout(context!!, attrs) {
private val mTouchSlop: Int = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledTouchSlop
private var mPrevX = 0f
@SuppressLint("Recycle")
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (event.action) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> mPrevX = MotionEvent.obtain(event).x
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            val eventX = event.x
            val xDiff = abs(eventX - mPrevX)
            if (xDiff > mTouchSlop) {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event)
}
```